# Как зашифровать числа

Tags: php

Как зашифровать числа например, 1 или 2 было как dFf3 с помощью PHP?
нужно зашифровать id пользователя с возможностью расшифровки!

Comment: А расшифровывать потом - надо?

Comment: нужно зашифровать id пользователя с возможностью расшифровки

Comment: Зачем вам нужно это шифрование?

Answer (score 2):

Простенький вариант, одна функция кодирует, другая раскодирует, 
переменную $secure задать свою

```
function soCode($value){
  $secure = 19537;
  return dechex(($secure + $value * 2) * 3);
}

function deSoCode($value){
  $secure = 19537;
  return ((hexdec($value) / 3) - $secure) / 2;
}
```

пример использования:

```
$result = soCode(1);
echo $result . "<br />";
echo deSoCode($result);
```

Comment: Из задачи  не совсем понятно что хотят получить, для шифрования я бы добавил ещё соль, отредактирую выше свой ответ

Comment: Поэтому нужно требовать пояснений и закрывать вопрос, а не отвечать

Comment: нужно зашифровать id пользователя с возможностью расшифровки

Comment: @nonn, и чем Вам не подошёл данный ответ?